# Symfony 3 Form EntityType field does not take empty choices

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

Following code keeps loading when $this->getChoices() return an empty array.

```
$builder->add('username', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'ApiBundle:User',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'label' => 'User',
        'choices' => $this->getChoices(),
        'required' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Select...',
));
```

I know the one solution would be to change **EntityType** with **ChoiceType** when choices are empty. However, would like to know any better fixes for this issue.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Any idea on why does it not work with empty choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the way I solved, please post your answer if someone knows the better way to do it.

```
 if($this->getChoices()) {
    $builder->add('username', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'ApiBundle:User',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => 'User',
            'choices' => $this->getChoices(),
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Select...',
    ));
    } else {
    $builder->add('username', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'class' => 'ApiBundle:User',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => 'User',
            'choices' => null,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Select...',
    ));
    }
```